# SharePoint Online can't open sites and documents until first refresh

Tags: sharepoint-online

When I open our company's SharePoint Online start page (or any file from bookmarks), I get this:

[image]

When I *reload* the page, it works as expected.
Some of my co-workers also experienced the problem so it is not related to me.

Our administrator checked the [Status page](https://status.office365.com/) of our Office 365 services and it shows *no problems* with SharePoint.

What does this problem indicate then?

Comment: I see this all the time with demo tenants, but never with a "real" tenant. I suspect those run on different architectures. I'd open a support ticket, no one on this site can help with that.